# Factorization of $ax^2 +bx+c$

Tags: number-theory

Assume {$a, b, c$} is coprime. I know $ax^2+bx+c$ can always be factorised as $a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ with the quadratic formula where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be integers, rational, irrational, or imaginary.

Based on experience, I think I can claim that with a proper choice of integers $a_1$ and $a_2$ where $a_1a_2=a$, we have $ax^2+bx+c=(a_1x+h)(a_2x+k)$ with $h, k$ being both integers, irrational, or imaginary. But I cannot prove it rigorously that it is not possible for one of the $h$ and $k$ being integer while the other one being a fraction no matter how we choose $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Having been trying to play with the algebra and lots of numerical experience, I still could not figure out a rigorously proof for it. I feel like it is number theory stuff which I am not good at.

Comment: I think you mean $a,b,c$ to be integers. In that case, your quadratic factors if and only if the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$  is the square of an integer. In case the discriminant is precisely $0,$ the quadratic is $\pm 1$ times a square

Comment: This is implied by Gauss's lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)

Comment: For $(a,b,c)=(4,5,1)$, if we choose $(a_1,a_2)=(2,2)$, then $(h,k)=\left(2,\frac 12\right)$ works since $4x^2+5x+1=(2x+2)\left(2x+\frac 12\right)$.